# java.jms.MapMessage getString property

Tags: java, string, jms

I searched only for an answer, but haven't found any answer. 
Thanks for your time.
I have some problem on an `if` statement done on a `String` sent via JMS Queue using map.message 
This is the code (the part is only the creation and the retrivial of information from the `MapMessage`)

**Message creation**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (Math.random() < 0.5f) {
    msg.setStringProperty("tipo", "MUL");
    msg.setBoolean("operazione", true);
    } else {
    msg.setStringProperty("tipo", "SUM");
    msg.setBoolean("operazione", false);
    }
    msg.setInt("operando1", (int) (Math.random() * 100));
    msg.setInt("operando2", (int) (Math.random() * 100));
    sender.send(msg);

}
```

**Data retrieval from the message**

```
int op1 = 0, op2 = 0, ris = 0;
String tipo = null;
int k = 0;
boolean operazione;

public MyListener() {
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public void onMessage(Message msg) {
    java.rmi.registry.Registry r;
    try {
        r = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();

        ICounter ic = (ICounter) r.lookup("counter");
        MapMessage message = (MapMessage) msg;
        tipo = "" + message.getStringProperty("tipo");
        System.out.println(tipo);
        op1 = message.getInt("operando1");
        op2 = message.getInt("operando2");
        operazione = message.getBoolean("operazione");
        if (operazione) {
        ris = ic.moltiplica(op1, op2);
        System.out.println("moltiplico");
        } else if (!operazione) {
        ris = ic.somma(op1, op2);
        System.out.println("sommo");
        } else {
        System.out.println("messaggio non valido");
        }
    } 
}
```

If I try to avoid the boolean variable in the `if` statament using 
`if(tipo.equals("MUL"))` or `if(tipo.equals("SUM"))` the code run always the else branch even if the the print of the tipo variables equals to SUM or MUL, Anyone knows why? thanks.
I tried to cast the `msg.getStringProperty("tipo")` or using `==` instead of `equals` .The ICounter is RMI interface and it works properly.

Comment: You should not declare your variables at the instance level (`op1, op2, tipo`etc.) as there are great chances that the `onMessage`method will be called in parallel, depending on your Q Manager and setup. Also why do you concatenate `""` to `message.getStringProperty("tipo")`? Finally what are the `ic` and `r.lookup()` stanza for?r Also why are you using a MapMessage and not a plain `Message`message as you don't set the body of the message (a `Map`..)

Comment: I concatenated `""` to `message.getStringProperty("tipo")`to cast it into a `String` variable. `ic` is an instance of the interface `ICounter` (that implements 2 methods addition and multiplication ) and i use `r.lookup()` because i use RMI and`ICounter` is a remote interface. I use `MapMessage` because this is the text of an old exam

Comment: FYI `getStringProperty()`already returns a `String`. Did you try to declare all the variables inside the `onMessage()` method insetad at the instance level?

Comment: Yes i tried, But that didn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using 
`if(tipo.compereTo("SUM")==0)`
instead of `if(tipo=="SUM")`or `if(tipo.equals("SUM"))`

Anyone can tell me why ? thanks